# String Replace column data with data from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

TableA:

```
ID       Values
---------------
1         Q
2         B
3         TA
4         BS

TableB:

RawValue    Value
------------------
[1][4]      QBS
[2][1][3]   BQTA
```

I need to generate TableB values with its given RawValues. each [X] in rawvalue is the ID coulmn of TableA and shoud be replace with its value .

[1][4]  means that Value of TableA with has ID of 1 (Q) and Value of TableA with has ID of 4 (BS) then should equal to QBS.

can anyone suggest a way to do it?

this is what I have already tried:

```
    update tableb set value=replace(rawvalue,'[' + (select id from tablea where id = cast(replace(replace(rawdata,'[',''),']','') as int)) + ']',
(select values from tablea where id = cast(replace(replace(rawdata,'[',''),']','') as int)))
```

By the way: this is still in test process and I can totally change tables, rowvalue format and replacement methods if anyone has a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @tableA table (id int, value varchar(50))
insert into @tableA (id, value)
select 1, 'Q' union all
select 2, 'B' union all
select 3, 'TA' union all
select 4, 'BS'

declare @tableB table (rawdata varchar(255), value varchar(255))
insert into @tableB (rawdata)
select '[1][4]' union all -- QBS
select '[2][1][3]' -- BQTA


update b
set value = (
        select a.value + ''
        from @tableA a
        cross apply (select charindex ('[' + cast (a.id as varchar(50)) + ']', b.rawdata) as pos) p
        where pos > 0
        order by pos
        for xml path('')
    )
from @tableB b

select * from @tableB
```

P.S. I would recommend not to name field similar to reserved keywords (I mean **Values**).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like a charm. although I didn't understand a bit how code works.

Answer (score 0):

Turn `RawValue` into XML, shred the XML to get one row for each value in `RawValue` and join to `TableA` to get the value.

Use the `for xml path()` trick to concatenate the values from `TableA`.

```
update TableB
set Value = (
            select T.Value as '*'
            from (
                 select row_number() over(order by T2.X) as SortOrder,
                        TableA.Value
                 from (select cast(replace(replace(TableB.RawValue, '[', '<x>'), ']', '</x>') as xml)) as T1(X)
                   cross apply T1.X.nodes('x') as T2(X)
                   inner join TableA
                     on TableA.ID = T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'int')
                 ) as T
            order by T.SortOrder
            for xml path('')
            )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/219b7/3)